# Selenium Wait for Page Source Contains

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was just wondering if there's an elegant way to utilize `ExpectedConditions` or something else to have my code wait for a page's source to contain a given string until a given timeout.  I know I can use something like this if I wanted to use a specific element's locator ...

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("foobar")));
```

But I wanted to accomplish this without using a locator for a specific element, and just use the whole page source as my reference instead.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "whole page source"? How do you want to set a condition? </html> present?

Comment: @swinkler yeah just html present

Comment: But again, <html> is a element which will be located with By.ByTagName

Comment: @swinkler That's fine, I just didn't want it to be a specific subelement. Could you post the answer you had in mind so I could see what you're talking about better.  Let's say we're waiting for page source to contain "foobar" like in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant have the all elements as a condition for waiting. When switching page weddriver automaticly wait for the page to load. WHen it has finished loading the HTML elements it continues. But it doesnt wait for JavaScript to execute. A lot of webpages today uses JavaScript to populate the webpage after the HTML has loaded.

What you should do is wait for every element you want to use.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by)));
```

or

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element))h;
```

Comment: why is the `.refreshed()` necessary?

Comment: It refreshes the dom where it searches for the element

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for document's `readyState` to become `complete`. Run the javascript `return document.readyState").equals("complete")` against the web page that is loading.

```
void waitForLoad(WebDriver driver) {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
            }
        };
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(pageLoadCondition);
}
```

And then you can get the page source:

```
driver.getPageSource();
```

And then verify that the pageSource contains what you are looking for:

```
driver.getPageSource().contains("your element/tag");
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: As I stated in my answer. This only waits for the HTML elements to be present on the page when it is fully loaded. Any element added afterwards will be unavailable from the webdriver

Comment: How about using scriptTimeout? Does that wait for the Ajax stuff?

Comment: You dont want to wait for alla JavaScripts to finish. Some of them may never finish.

Answer (score 0):

Without depending on visibility, you could check if an element is present in the DOM:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.tagName("html")));
```

If you want to refer to individual text, you can implement `ExpectedCondition<T>` and create your own condition class. The mentioned interface has access to the WebDriver (due to super-interface `com.google.common.base.Function<WebDriver,T>`).

In the method `apply` you could use the `WebDriver` and call method `getPageSource()` to have `String` presenting the page source. Check the `String` for whatever you prefer.

Comment: I believe the method name is `By.tagName`.